# fetch a column from a file based on another column

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which contains approximately 5 million records, as follows: -

```
1223423,21,foo,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,45,267,index1
4234234,34,bar,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5,34,2323,index2
325423,23,foo,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,23,1232,index3
2131,23,bar,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5,22,4334,index4
1231,43,cat,val1,val2val3,val4,val5,96,4598,index5
4596,87,cat,val1,val2val3,val4,val5,08,234,index6
```

Desired output :

```
foo,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5 : index1,index3
bar,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5 : index2,index4
cat,val1,val2val3,val4,val5 : index5,index6
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: the line cat,val1,val2val3,val4,val5 . val1val2 has no comma(,) between them??

Answer (score 0):

try this if works

```
awk -F, '{a[$3$4$5$6$7$8]++;if(a[$3$4$5$6$7$8] > 1)k[$3$4$5$6$7$8]=k[$3$4$5$6$7$8]","$11;else k[$3$4$5$6$7$8]=$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8":"$11}'END'{for(i in k) print k[i]}' data
```

I have doubt on line

```
4596,87,cat,val1,val2val3,val4,val5,08,234,index6
```

there is no comma(,) between `val2val3`?? it this correct??

Comment: My Bad...its typo....there is comma (,) between val2 & val3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to build an array (in memory) as you read the file – then END-process that array to output as required.

However many fields remain after removing the first 2 and last 3 fields from a record, become the key to the array.

```
awk -F, '{ ix=$NF
           sub( "[^,]+,[^,]+,","")       # delete first 2 fields
           sub(",[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$","") # delete last 3 fields
           a[$0]=a[$0] ","ix }  
      END{ for( r in a ) { sub(",","",a[r]);  print r" : "a[r] }
         }' file
```

---

output:

```
cat,val1,val2val3,val4,val5 : index5,index6
bar,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5 : index2,index4
foo,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5 : index1,index3
```

Answer (score 0):

With very large files it is often best to sort the data so the rest is easier
and doesnt need any memory. sort is designed to handle very large data sets.

The following removes the unwanted columns, sorts the data, then awk just
suppresses the duplicated columns without needing to remember more than
one line. The final sort is optional, to get the indexes in order.

```
cut -d, -f 3-8,11 |
sort |
awk -F, '
{ new = sprintf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
  if(new==last)printf ",%s",$7
  else{ printf "%s%s: %s",newline,new,$7
        last = new
        newline = "\n"
  }
}
END{printf "\n"}
' |
sort -t: -k 2
```